# Creating WP blog archive - date rage .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, .htaccess

Based on the redirect below, How could I get it to redirect from 2007-2010?

```
 RedirectMatch 301 ^/2010/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ http://archive.website.com/2010/$1/$2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
 RedirectMatch 301 ^/(200[7-9]|2010)/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ http://archive.website.com/$1/$2/$3
```